# Unable to Delete and redraw or Draw over plot axes based on PYQT widget state change

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am  trying to make a dynamic chart where the patches are updated when the user moves a slider. I am using the matplotlib and pyqt packages that came with anaconda python. The code i have runs and does the drawing properly once but when I move the slider the update fails.

I have the following

my layout is created with the following class

```
class plotArea(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(plotArea, self).__init__()
    self.init()

def init(self):
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.setLayout(grid)
    title = QtGui.QLabel('Title')
    sldTime = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    sldLevel = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    plot = MyDynamicMplCanvas()
    sldTime.valueChanged[int].connect(plot.changeValue)
    sldLevel.valueChanged[int].connect(plot.changeValue)
    grid.addWidget(title, 0, 0, 1, 10)
    grid.addWidget(sldLevel, 1, 0, 10, 1)
    grid.addWidget(sldTime, 11, 1, 1, 9)
    grid.addWidget(plot, 1, 1, 9, 9)
```

my chart class with the drawing and update method are shown below

```
class MyDynamicMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

"""A canvas that updates itself every second with a new plot."""
def __init__(self):
    fig = Figure()
    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
    chart = fig.add_subplot(111)
    chart.set_xlim([0, 4])
    chart.set_ylim([0, 4])
    self.draw_lattice(chart)

def draw_lattice(self, chart):

    min_val = 0
    max_val = 100
    my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min_val, max_val)
    color_i = my_cmap(norm(np.random.uniform(0, 100)))
    my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
    square = Rectangle((1, 1), 1, 1, alpha=0.5, facecolor=color_i,
    edgecolor='k')
    chart.add_patch(square)

    def changeValue(self,chart):
        self.draw_lattice(chart)
```

Since both methods are in the same class there shouldnt be any scoping issues and the code does work on the initial pass but gives the following error if I move the slider.

```
  chart.add_patch(square)
```

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add_patch'

I have been struggling with this for a bit what am i doing wrong? Do I need to delete the subplot? I am not sure why calling from changeValue causes the code to fail. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you define chart in the init method, you don't actually keep a reference to it.  To actually keep it you need to turn the line

```
chart = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

to

```
self.chart = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

then reference it using `self.chart`.

You are passing an integer into your slot, which will be the `chart` argument when the signal is generated, which is why you get that `int` error - `chart` is treated as an Axes object in the code, but any events will put an integer into that variable.  I would change the input to your slot to be the slidervalue, and just reference `self.chart` to update your plot.

Comment: Thanks for the response do I need to use the format self.variable_name for all instances?

Comment: For anything to which you need to keep a reference, yes - it becomes an attribute of the class which you then can access from self in all the methods - self is always the first argument.